unable to add pro subncription in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
unable to add pro subscription in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pro", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'pkg_resources.extern' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py)

